# Find if a phrase within a range of columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am analyzing big data. One of the column I am looking at has phrases like "car" and "car,bike,scooter". Now I used "countif" to find out the number of times the phrase "car" appears, but I also want to count the number of time car appears in columns in general, regardless of if there are other phrases that follow "car" within the same cell. I understand this might be a very noob question, but please understand that I am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Something like `=COUNTIF(A:A,"*car*")`

Comment: @BigBen goodness, thank you kind sir.

Comment: Bear in mind that `*car*` will also count "carpet" and "Vicar".